# Create regular expression to separate each word from . (dot)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to separate each word from `.` (dot) in JavaScript.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "in.k1.k2.k3.k4.com"
  var result
  var match
  if (match = url.match(/^[^\.]+\.(.+\..+)$/)) {
    console.log(match);
  }
}
```

Actual result is:

```
match[0] : in.k1.k2.k3.k4.com
match[1] : k1.k2.k3.k4.com
```

Expected result is:

```
match[0] : in.k1.k2.k3.k4.com
match[1] : k1.k2.k3.k4.com
match[2] : k2.k3.k4.com
match[3] : k3.k4.com
match[4] : k4.com
```

Please help me to create perfect regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex, in this case, might not be the best choice. You could simply split your string at the `.` and then join them when you need it.

```js
function recursivelySplitText(arrayOfString, output) {
  // check if the output is set, otherwise create it.
  if(!output) {
    output = [];
  }
  // we add the current value to the output
  output.push(arrayOfString.join('.'));
  // we remove the first element of the array
  arrayOfString.splice(0, 1);
  // if we just have one element left in the array ( com )  we return the array
  // otherwise, we call the function again with the newly splitted array.
  return arrayOfString.length === 1 ? output : recursivelySplitText(arrayOfString, output);
}

const text = 'in.k1.k2.k3.k4.com';
// we need to split it first to have an array of string rather than a string.
console.log(recursivelySplitText(text.split('.')));
```

Here i used recursion because it is fun, but it is not the only way of getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regex you could use a combination of `split()` and `map()` to create the output array you require. Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var arr = "in.k1.k2.k3.k4.com".split('.');
  var output = arr.map((v, i) => arr.slice(i).join('.'));
  
  console.log(output);
}

myFunction();
```